# Problem with BitmapFactory.decodeResource

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-drawable

i am trying to develop a Tank game, so I need to build 2 different Bitmap tanks.
I have created a Java class called **Tank.java**, where i create my tank, but the problem is i need create 2 different models of tank, but with my class, i can only create one specific kind of tank.

```
public class Tank {

private int x,y;
int width, height;
Bitmap tank1

Tank(int screenY, Resources res){

    tank1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.azul_tanque);
    width = tank1.getWidth();
    height = tank1.getHeight();
    width /=4;
    height/=4;

    width *= (int)screenRatioX;
    height *= (int)screenRatioY;

    tank1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tank1,width,height,false);

    setY(screenY / 2);

}

}
```

You can see here the class, but the problem is i call this class from another class which paint this object in a canvas.

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

private Thread thread;
private Boolean isPlaying;

Paint paint;

public static float screenRatioX, screenRatioY;


private Tank tank;
private Tank tank2;


public GameView(Context context, int screenX, int screenY) {
    super(context);

    background = new Background(screenX,screenY,getResources());

    paint = new Paint();

    screenRatioX = 2340f / screenX;
    screenRatioY= 1080f / screenY;

    tank = new Tank(screenY,getResources());
    
    tank2 = new Tank(screenY,getResources());


}

@Override
public void run() {

    while(isPlaying){
        update();
        draw();
        sleep();
    }


}


private void draw(){
    if(getHolder().getSurface().isValid()){
        Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawBitmap(background.background,background.x,background.y,paint);
        tank.setX((int)(64 * screenRatioX));
        tank2.setX((int)(2000 * screenRatioX));
        canvas.drawBitmap(tank.getTank(),tank.getX(),tank.getY(),paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(tank2.getTank(),tank2.getX(),tank2.getY(),paint);
        getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);


    }

}
```

In this class, I call the Tank´s constructor but i cant choose which drawable i want to use.
I tried to create another Tank´s constructor with this semantic:

**Tank(int screenY, Resources res, Drawable myTank).**

In GameView class i instantiate like this:

**tank = new Tank(screenY,getResources,getResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.mytank));**

But when i construct the tank on the new tank´s constructor it didnt work, because the method:

**tank1= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,myTank)** gives me an error, due the **BitmapFactory.decodeResource** needs an **int** like second argument but in the old constructor i use **R.drawable.azul_tanque** and i thought that the second arguments needs a **Drawable**.

So Anyone can help me, how can i code the new constructor to create a new Tank choosing the Drawable in GameView class.

Thank you very much for your time guys.

Pd: If you see methods which don't appear here is because i deleted them, but for now this code paint me two same tanks on my screen.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to work with Bitmap as parameter you can do a simple if else and pass a switcher variable. Like this:

Constructor:

```
Tank(int screenY, Resources res, int switcher) {
if(switcher == 1)
    tank1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.azul_tanque);
else
    tank1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.second_tank);
```

GameView:

```
tank = new Tank(screenY,getResources(), 1);

tank2 = new Tank(screenY,getResources(), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the drawable resource id in the constructor.

```java
Tank(int screenY, Resources res, int resourceId){

    tank1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resourceId);
    width = tank1.getWidth();
    height = tank1.getHeight();
    width /=4;
    height/=4;

    width *= (int)screenRatioX;
    height *= (int)screenRatioY;

    tank1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tank1,width,height,false);

    setY(screenY / 2);

}
```

Now you can pass any image for the tank.